# Injest Pipeline Script for nested list of array - retrieve and copy data data from old field to new field in Kibana

Tags: mapping, kibana, elastic-stack, aws-elasticsearch

My goals -

1. Find the existing field if present `(responseBody.results[i].statusCode)` and copy it's value into a new field `(embedded_error_code )` at **runtime**
2. My original field is a list of array. Below is the structure of my original field - `(responseBody.results[i].statusCode)`

```
 "responseBody": {
      "results": [
        {
          "hasErrors": false,
          "statusCode": 201,
          "uniqueId": "***",
          "messageId": null,
          "customerId": "***",
          "developerMessage": "SUCCESS",
          "userMessage": "SUCCESS",
          "errors": []
        }
      ]
    },
```

My working Script when used with `_update_by_query`

```
POST _scripts/test-embedded-script
{
  "script": {
    "lang" : "painless",
     "source": """
        if(ctx._source.responseBody != null )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.responseBody.results.length; ++i) 
            {
              ctx._source.embedded_error_code = ctx._source.responseBody.results[i].statusCode;
            } 
        }"""
  }
}
```

My defined pipeline -

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/apiproxy-embedded
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "id": "test-embedded-script"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to run the above script runtime, that's why I'm using Injest Pipeline
`test-embedded-script` isn't working in `apiproxy-embedded` pipeline.
Please help me to write this script as one of the processors of my pipeline.

**NOTE : I'm not mapping/indexing my original field i.e. `responseBody.results[i].statusCode`  and I don't want to map this field as well because it's of no use. I want to map new field only i.e. `embedded_error_code`.**